# Scheme - adding values to list recursively

Tags: list, recursion, append, scheme

I am trying to make a function in scheme that adds values to an empty list recursively.

I have defined an empty list:

```
(define empty '() )
```

And I have defined a function that should add values to the list:

```
(define (recapp empt x)
    (if (= 0 x)
      empt
      (begin
         (append empt x)
         (recapp empt (- x 1)))))
```

When I enter to Scheme (recapp empty 5) I get an empty list even though I would like to get (1 2 3 4 5). What is the problem?

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that (append empt x) does not modify the value of `empt`. Thus you are just passing `empt` (value '()) through `recapp` `X` (original argument value) times.

```
(define (recapp empt x)
    (if (= 0 x)
      empt
      (recapp (cons x empt) (- x 1))))
```

Is closer to what you want. Also note the primative `iota` has similar functionality.

Comment: `iota` is not actually a primitive. It's provided by SRFI 1. Racket, for example, provides `range` instead (with different argument order to `iota`).

Comment: Thanks!! Unfortunately I cannot yet vote your answer upwards:/